# Calculated Value Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, flow

I have a list with about 15 columns. I need to have one of my columns pull the *initial value* entered (only) of one of the other columns.

*Example:*

**[Column A]** is blank then changes to 2/2/2023 .... **[Column B]** should read as 2/2/2023 <-- copies the initial value entered

Even if **[Column A]** later changes to 3/3/2023, I would need **[Column B]** to stay as 2/2/2023

I wasn't sure if I needed a "IS" function, but wasn't sure where or how to begin. Any help is definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is easily possible using calculated column as you cannot read previous value of Column A to check it was blank.

However, you can easily to it using Power automate flow. Follow the steps:

1. Run a Power automate flow on item creation/update (as per your requirements)
2. Check if Column B is empty and Column A is not empty
3. If above condition is true > Update column B

You can even use the trigger conditions based on if Column B is empty or not to avoid unnecessary flow runs.